# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPageLayout() on null in

Tags: magento2, php, template

Magento 2.2.5 version. Every time trying to go to product page I get error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPageLayout() on null in /var/www/html/app/code/MGS/Mpanel/Helper/Data.php:1445 Stack   trace: #0     /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/templates/produ  ct/list/items.phtml(175): MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data->getProductLayout(NULL) 
#1   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59):   include('/var/www/html/a...') 
#2  /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\TargetRule\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Related\Interceptor), '/var/www/html/a...', Array) 
#3 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/TargetRule/Block/Catalog/Product/ProductList/Related/Interceptor.php(622): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/a...') 
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\TargetRule\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Related\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/html/a...') 
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/mage in /var/www/html/app/code/MGS/Mpanel/Helper/Data.php on line 1445
```

Code in Data.php in 1445 line is:

```
public function getProductLayout($product){
    $pageLayout = $product->getPageLayout();

    if($pageLayout==''){
        $pageLayout = $this->getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/product_layout');
    }

    if($pageLayout==''){
        $pageLayout = '1column';
    }

    return $pageLayout;
}
```

I am using custom template.
Any help what to check?

Comment: Looks like the $product parameter is null so try to call ->getPageLayout() on a null variable throws the error. I guess the next step is to find why is the custom items.phtml template passing a null value to the getProductLayout method.  I'd highly recommend getting Xdebug setup to speed debugging these types of issues.

Comment: I can't setup Xdebug.Never used it before

Answer (score 1):

We should check `$product->getPageLayout()` doesn't return null.

```
if ($product->getPageLayout()) {
   // Your logic here
}
```